# Lazy-Loading Nested and Linked Resources via AJAX in AngularJS?

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs, rest, json-ld

I'm looking for either an already-existing javascript library (module for AngularJS) or at least a best-practice technique for dealing with loading nested resources automatically when a view needs them, given an already-loaded parent resource.

Here's an example, and assume **user** actually came from some REST API via ajax.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('TestController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.user = {
      name: "John Smith",
      creditCard: {
        "network": "Visa"
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">{{user.creditCard.network}}</div>
</div>
```

Now assume user, credit cards, and other resources are too big to load all in one api call. That is, I don't want to HAVE to send an entire graph of resources connected to user. If I include a user's "friends" collection by default, that could be my entire database!!

I know that's where [json-ld](http://json-ld.org/) and [json-hal](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) start to come in, in that they "hyperlink" the resources per se. If I were to use HAL:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('TestController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.user = {
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "/api/v1.0/user/1231213"
        },
        "creditCard": {
          "href": "/api/v1.0/creditCard/324324234"
        },
      },
      name: "John Smith"          
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">{{user.creditCard.network}}</div>
</div>
```

With that, of course I can just manually $http request details about the credit card (knowing that I need to show information about the credit card):

```js
$http({
  url: user._links.creditCard.href
}).success(function(resp) {
  user.creditCard = resp;
});
```

**Now, here is my question: is it a good idea, and if so, how (using an existing AngularJS library or otherwise) get any nested resource like creditCard to load automatically ONLY when AngularJS sees that I need it in a view?** This is especially important for when the view is asking for properties of members in an array, and when the controller doesn't necessarily know the structure/schema of the data (only the view does).

Complex example: what if I need user.creditCard.transactions[i].recipient.name and I only have the root user object (and through HAL I know user has a creditCard nested object)? This technique/library would need to reconcile first creditCard, then transactions, then recipient.

I'm also weighing the problem of whether that's a benefit, given the original scenario is 1 API call and potentially a huge response, versus potentially dozens or hundreds of API calls, each with a small payload, that at worst is the same aggregate size as the former.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE: I'm looking into angular-resource ($resource) and Restangular, not sure if they'll get me 50% or 100% there.**

**Extra Credit:** If I really want to be fancy and optimize further ... Let's say each of the parent objects between user and recipient are too heavy, and the REST API is fully-nested. That is, I can just call /user/1/creditCard/transactions/recipients or something and get the recipient resource directly. Could the above suggestion maybe use an interceptor or whatever to call that instead?